# How are runway changes performed when radar vectoring is available?

Tags: air-traffic-control, runways

When the time comes to make a runway change, let's say because wind has changed direction, how is this performed?

- Aircraft might already be on finals, what does ATC do? Do they ask them if they want to continue with the approach or be vectored to another runway?
- Aircraft might not be on finals but being vectored to the finals. Same question here.
- Finally, there might be aircraft on the ground already taxied to the runway. Do they takeoff anyway or do they taxi to the new runway?

Comment: Related: [How does a large airport switch flow?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9126/how-does-a-large-airport-switch-flow)

Comment: @mins That pretty much answers the question. But what can be done so that if someone else interested comes across the question? As far as I know "runway change" is close to the terminology while "flow switching" is not. I bet that if I delete this one, there might be someone else asking the same after a while...

Comment: @steliosAdamantidis Technically, flow change/switch is what you're talking about in this question, a runway change is literally changing a runway an aircraft is assigned to. So a simple change from the Left to the Right is a runway change, changing from 35L/R to 17L/R is a flow change, or changing the active runways. Though technically a flow change is a subset of runway changes.

Comment: You don't have to delete your question, it's a good question which happens to be already answered. If you don't delete it, it will be marked as *duplicate* and the other URL will be included in the duplicate note. People reaching your question in their search will continue to the other by clicking the link. If you want to delete it, you may do so indeed.

Comment: @mins That sounds good.